# Android: Button onClick description in custom class

Tags: android

My **button**:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn_Scr1_to_Scr2"
        android:text="Text" 
        android:onClick="Go_to_Scr2"/>
```

My **method**:

```
public void Go_to_Scr2(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);            
    }
```

If I use it in **main activity** class:

```
public class MainScreenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

    }
    public void Go_to_Scr2(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

... it works.

But, if i try to use this metod in **custom** class:

```
public class MyMethods extends MainScreenActivity {
    public void Go_to_Scr2(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);        
    }
}
```

...it causes crash my app.

Summary: I have a method that is in the class that extends Context class with which View was created, but it is doesn't works (NoSuchMethodException in Log Cat):

```
04-30 13:03:50.431: E/AndroidRuntime(22355): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Go_to_Scr2 [class android.view.View]
04-30 13:03:50.431: E/AndroidRuntime(22355):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
04-30 13:03:50.431: E/AndroidRuntime(22355):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
04-30 13:03:50.431: E/AndroidRuntime(22355):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3578)
04-30 13:03:50.431: E/AndroidRuntime(22355):    ... 11 more
```

Where is my mistake? Thanks!

Comment: in which xml you are writing code for button for both pages

Comment: `android:onClick` attribute tries to find the proper method using reflection. It's possible that this fails when you try to do it with subclasses. Generally speaking I dislike using the `android:onCLick` attribute.

Comment: Sree, in main_screen.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Documents says "Android system calls the activity's public method. In order for this to work, the method must be public and accept a View as its only parameter."

It should work only in Activity class.

Comment: I think, that this line will solve the problem: public class MyMethods extends MainScreenActivity